# Flatpickr set minDate and maxDate dynamically by other field value in field setting without custom JS

Tags: javascript, date, flatpickr

How could I set the minDate of a "end date" field to by dynamically bigger than the "start date" field by references to the start date input id without custom Js to track the start date and date.

I didn't see in the docs any solutions for this other then hard code minDate and maxDate.

Something like:

```
maxDate: "#start-date-id"
```

which will use value of minDate of "end date" based on the current value in "start date" input field

Comment: If I were using jQuery UI datepicker, I would trap the change event of first datepicker to set the min date of second datepicker. I am sure it is possible in flatpickr too.

Comment: @SalmanA—I think the OP is aware of that approach and wants to know if there's an alternative using [flatpickr](https://flatpickr.js.org).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't, although this would be an excellent feature for what I imagine is a pretty common use case.